# QGIS - how to move layer files while project is open

Tags: qgis-2.18, qgis-3

I want to move layer files (within browser directory structure) while my QGIS project is still open - therefore allowing the project to update its relative link to that file. ARCGIS does this, but not QGIS? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a layer file is moved QGIS will miss that file until u re-add it again from new location of that same file. I am affraid there is no workaround for that one.

Comment: Thanks. I've worked with html files and web development for years and it was a basic 'tool' from the outset for those software packages.